# Does impeller design have a specific cause on how the fluid will flow in a centrifugal pump?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pumps

I am a student learning about centrifugal pumps in my studies.

I’ve learnt about the 3 different type of flows - axial, radial and mixed.

I’ve also learnt about different impeller designs - mainly - opened, semi-enclosed, enclosed.

I was wondering, how does these 2 link together ? For the types of flow classifications, when does these different flows occurs ? And does the impeller design have a specific cause on how the fluid will flow ?

And also which flow is ideal to operate under ?

Comment: Are there any advantages of radial v axial for a particular flow rate or head or vice versa? What do your notes and references tell you?

Comment: @SolarMike my notes on “classification by impeller design” has the following subpoints- “open-end suction-radial flow” , “semi-enclosed-end suction- radial flow” , “enclosed-end suction- radial flow” . I was wondering if these 3 impeller design causes radial flow ?

Comment: Grundfos (one of the big pump manufacturers) has a really good pump handbook that might answer some of your questions: https://grundfos.com/grundfos-for-engineers/featured-themes/Featured-theme-Pump-Handbook.html